# Determining the origin of compiler flags

Tags: numpy, gfortran, f2py

When compiling, how can you determine what compiler flags are set?  I'm dealing with a weird issue where, if I don't have any environmental variables set:

```
$ env | grep FLAG
$
```

then gfortran uses all these flags:
`-Wall -arch i686 -arch x86_64 -Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle`

Whereas, in an environment where these are set

```
$ env | grep FLAG
LDFLAGS=
CCFLAGS=
CXXFLAGS=
CFLAGS=
FFLAGS=
```

the only flag is: `-Wall`

I'm just lost as to how to ensure a consistent build environment when distributing code.

EDIT: Further investigation hints that this magic may happen in `numpy.distutils.fcompiler`, but I don't know!

Comment: It seems you can override the default compiler flags by doing `f2py -c --verbose  --opt='-O0' modules.pyf modules.f90`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not at all sure about Numpy, but I `distutils` uses `distutils.sysconfig.customize_compiler` to set the flags.

By default this uses the flags that were set in the Makefile when your interpreter was built, but they can be added to by environment variables.